# Gridview show edit button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Im having some issues with the edit button inside a gridview.
When you click edit in the gridview, the cancel  button gets the same cssclass as the edit button. So my cancel button gets the same edit icon.

I want to change this so that the cancel button gets a different css-class. So I can give it the right icon instead of an edit ico :)

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="edit-sprite"></asp:CommandField>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use TemplateFields instead of CommandFields:

```
     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton"
                            runat="server"
                            CssClass="EditButton"
                            CommandName="Edit" 
                            Text="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton"
                            runat="server"
                            CssClass="UpdateButton"
                            CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Update" />&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Cancel"
                            runat="server"
                            CssClass="CancelButton"
                            CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton"
                        CssClass="DeleteButton"
                        Text="Delete"
                        CommandName="Delete" 
                        runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice way to fix it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with CSS instead:

table tr td .edit_sprite:first-child{/*img icon edit*/}

table tr td .edit_sprite{/*img icon cancel*/}